# Import DMP file to oracle 19 c

Tags: sql, oracle, import, dmp

I tried to import a dmp file that was exported before, but it failed due to this error :

**Master table "PRODDTA"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_06" successfully loaded/unloaded
import done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
Warning: possible data loss in character set conversions
Starting "PRODDTA"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_06":  PRODDTA/********
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-39083: Object type USER:"PRODDTA" failed to create with error:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name**

I have created the user PRODDTA and granted all the privileges, but still it did not work, I don't know if it has a problem with schema or something.
I am not very familiar with Oracle, hope you can help !

Comment: `ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name` You are trying to import into the container database (CDB) and not the pluggable database (PDB). The username `PRODDTA` is not valid for a container database (usernames must begin with "C##"), and CDBs should not contain application data, regardless. Make sure you are using the correct service_name to connect to the pluggable database. Do _not_ use ORACLE_SID, as that most often only points to the container database.

Comment: I have created the pluggable database but when I execute the $impdp command I can't log in to it

Comment: whet impdp command are your running? are you sure you're using the proper service name for the pdb?

Comment: This is the command I tried: impdp system/oracle@ORCL directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdat.DMP log=PRODDTA_20210601.log
I trie to add scema and remap it but same problem

Comment: So if you specify '@oracle', we then need to see the tnsnames.ora entry for 'orcl'.  I'll bet that is the CDB.

Comment: That's it:
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )